# How many volumes CO2 will push out a champagne cork?

Tags: carbonation, mead, co2

I'm bottling a mead to pass out around Christmas time. I know mead isn't traditionally carbonated, but I want that satisfying cork pop and super effervescence. I have a floor champagne corker and an assortment of champagne bottles, belgian bottles and 375mL Vinnie bottles (Russian River). I'd rather not bottle everything in 750mL as I don't want to give away ALL my mead. So I'm thinking of using the 375mL Vinnie bottles, although I read somewhere Vinnie recommended not exceeding 4 volumes CO2 in those. They can take a champagne cork and cage. So my question is, will 4 volumes CO2 be enough to create that POP? At the very least I want them easy to pop out with great carbonation.

For the 750mL champagne bottles (with the dimples at bottom), I know they can handle ~7 volumes CO2, so that's what I'll do for those.

I think I'll experiment with a few before committing to bottling the full 10 gallons.

** EDIT: It has been a while since I corked and didn't think it through. I'll be using belgian corks for the 375mL and champagne corks for the real champagne bottles. I think 4 volumes CO2 will be plenty to pop the belgian cork... it just won't be the same as actual champagne. I don't know of any 375mL that can handle that kind of pressure (typically that have that dimple at the bottom).

Comment: It'll depend on the cork you use, but from what I've read, champagne is usually over 4 volumes, so standard cork in standard-width opening will not pop on it's own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"At 10 °C and 5.6 atm, a cooled champagne bottle (V = 0.75 L) would contain ca. 9.5 g of dissolved carbon dioxide (Table 2) [3]. Once the bottle is opened the CO2 pressure falls to at most 1 atm. Solubility considerations dictate that at 10 °C no more than 1.7 g will remain dissolved, so roughly 8 g of CO2 must suddenly be set free. This quantity of CO2 corresponds to a gas volume of 4 L — more than five times the volume of the bottle."

http://www.chemistryviews.org/details/ezine/889289/Sparkling_Wine_Champagne__Co__Part_2.html

This suggests that Champagne has roughly 6.3 volumes of CO2. 4 volumes should give a good POP and nice carbonation, but for the full Champagne effect you need to be up around 6-6.5, this will have to be in Champagne bottles or you will likely return one day to exploding bottles.